# How to insert rows in mysql Db , using light-orm in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, insert

i am new to ORM techniques and using light-orm for mysql and i am wondering how to insert any new row to the database using light-orm or suggest me the best ORM for nodejs and mysql.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally valid question. Without experience in ORM I tried to find an answer. That took me 30 minutes, and to find it I had to dig into the source-code itself, as there is no info in the documentation. (Will make a pull request afterwards).

Extracted from the [documentation](https://github.com/knyga/light-orm):

```
model.create(function(err, model) {});
```

That is good, but how do we get the `model` object you ask?

Here is the list of available methods in [Collection object](https://github.com/knyga/light-orm/blob/master/lib/typescript/Collection.ts):

```
/**
 * Create model
 * @param data Attributes, that will be setted during construction
 */
createModel(data: {});

/**
 * Create model
 * @param {boolean} add True, if created model should be added to models list
 */
createModel(add: boolean);

/**
 * Create model
 * @param data Attributes, that will be setted during construction
 * @param {boolean} add True, if created model should be added to models list
 */
createModel(data: {}, add: boolean);

createModel(options?: any, add?: boolean) : Model {
```

Granted you have a table `users` with fields: `login, password`.
Simple example (not tested) shall look something like the following:

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
    lightOrm = require('light-orm');

lightOrm.driver = mysql.createConnection(require('./connection.json'));
lightOrm.driver.connect();
var UsersCollection = new lightOrm.Collection('users');
var model = UsersCollection.createModel({login: "mylogin", password: "mypass"}, true);
model.create(); // Write the changes to database
```

Overall the *light-orm* looks fine, if you feel comfortable - keep using it.

Comment: *not working* is not very useful debug information. What exactly is wrong? Does it just execute without errors, but row is not added? Then try adding the line `model.create(cb);` in the end.

Comment: yes exactly the same thing is happening...and what is cb? it says cb is not defined.

Comment: i just removed cb and every thing is working now...great it worked !!!!! :) alas!!!!!thank you so much ....

Comment: cb stands for callback. You need to add a callback function there, it will also be able to catch and print errors. I am glad it worked, can you tell what exactly have you changed, so that I modify my answer?

Comment: i.e. you added `model.create();`?

Comment: yes and every thing else is same what you told. one more thing alan.. is this orm is good? compared to others? do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I am wrong person to ask for ORM opinion, never used one... I usually judge on whether a package is healthy based on downloads, forks, favourites, and other available stats.

Comment: alan can you tell me by looking into the source-code that how can i select some rows that are less than some value say 10

Comment: That is offtopic. Please read the documentation, there is `findOne` example using raw mysql query, I believe you can apply same for `find` method. Ask separate question if you cannot sort it out on your own.